# Download Manager supporting Drag & Drop

Tags: download-manager

I am looking for a download manager for 14.04 having drag and drop feature. I want to drag urls of files from Chromium then drop it in the download manager, instead of manually copy/add the urls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any app that does that but with uGet you can just copy the url and it well auto-detect the download thus creating a download process automatically.

http://uGetdm.com

Turn on the Clipboard Monitor.